# iOS webView inside scrollView : change height depending on the device orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiscrollview

I have a `webView` inside a `scrollView` (scrollView > mainView > webView and a view2 containing other components). In order to have only one scroll (the scrollView one) I calculate the height of the webView when it finish loading then I set the height of the mainView (its height is equal to the the webView + the view2 heights). My application supports the portrait and the landscape modes. To check when the rotation has changed I use:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Inside this function I call another one in order to reset the content of my `webView` (set the `html` content) so that the

```
(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.
```

can be recalled:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    //set the main view height
    [self.loader stopAnimating];
    CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
    float scrollHeight = contentSize.height + 270;
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad scrollHeight %f", scrollHeight);
    self.mainViewHeight.constant = scrollHeight;

}
```

**My problem:** when the application is at first in the `portrait` mode, the `scrollView` height is correct and works perfectly. When after that I change the rotation to the `landscape` mode, also the height is correct, but when I return the device to the `portrait`, the `scrollView` keep the height of the `landscape` mode even if I set the height in the `webViewDidFinishLoad`. When I put a breakpoint in `self.mainViewHeight.constant = scrollHeight;` I found that the `contentSize` height doesn't change when I go from the landscape to the portrait mode

Comment: check your support Device Orientations, maybe you doesn't support e.g. Upside Down, but rotate to it and wait something

Comment: @gaRik but I don't have this problem with the other screens (in the same app on the same device)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
   // change the frame for both portrait and landscape
   // check the orientation
   if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
    webView.frame = self.view.frame;
   }else {
    //
   }
}
```

Comment: <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'> add this to head of the html content

Comment: even if my problem is with the height and not the width?